# Broadcasting 2D array to 4D array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 2D array `x` of shape `(48, 7)`, and a 4D array `T` of shape `(48, 7, 48, 7)`. When I multiply `x * T`, python broadcasts the dimensions, but not in the way I expected (actually, I don´t understand how it is broadcasting). The following loop would achieve what I want:

```
for i in range(48):
    for j in range(7):
        Tx[i, j, :, :] = x[i, j] * T[i, j, :, :]
```

Where `Tx` is an array of shape `(48, 7, 48, 7)`. My question is, is there a way to achieve the same result using broadcasting?

Comment: Just reshape the array you want to multiply to fit the broadcasting rules numpy uses. I usually do smth like "Tx = x[:, :, None, None]*T" if i want to get what you want. I guess what numpy did was "Tx = x[None, None, :, :]*T" which is what you could have realised by reading [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: Thank you @yannziselman, after finding the docs I work my solution. It´s basically the same principle you stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcasting aligns trailing dimensions. In other words, `x * Tx` is doing this:

```
for i in range(48):
    for j in range(7):
        Tx[:, :, i, j] = x[i, j] * T[:, :, i, j]
```

To get the leading dimensions to line up, add unit dimensions to `x`:

```
Tx = x[..., None, None] * T
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.einsum` to specify the dimensions explicitly:

```
Tx = np.einsum('ij,ij...->ij...', x, T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Python broadcasts from the rightmost dimension and works its way to the left ([source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=When%20operating%20on%20two%20arrays%2C%20NumPy%20compares%20their%20shapes%20element%2Dwise.%20It%20starts%20with%20the%20trailing%20(i.e.%20rightmost)%20dimensions%20and%20works%20its%20way%20left.)).
By transposing the first two dimensions and the last two dimensions:

```
T = np.transpose(T, (2,3,0,1))
```

It will then broadcast the way I expected. After that, the resulting array can be transposed again to recover the original shape:

```
Tx = x*T
Tx = np.transpose(Tx, (2,3,0,1))
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to then transpose the output array to get the same result. Normally, vectorization works fastest along the contiguous dimension. This won't affect the multiplication, since you did not rewrite the data, but presumably you had a reason to make the last two dimensions contiguous. They won't be contiguous in the result after you do this.